# which version control is best suited for me?

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I know there are lots of questions with this title but I could find one which could clearly help me decide. I'm a part game developing team, and usualy there are 1 or 2 of each programmers, game designers, and artists envolved in a project. my main purpose is to keep the team in sync ( and the second important thing is to have a history of all thing we've done). Since there are non-programmers involved in the project i need the version control software you suggest to have a user-friendly gui to keep others from whining and make them shareevery thing they've produced through version control. While searching up until now I think I prefer to use SVN or GIT but I'm wondering which one suits our goals the best, can you suggest anything? (and I know about tortuisSVN and tortoisGIT)

Comment: Only you guys really will know which one suits your goals the best

Comment: but i guess i told you the whole story so i just needed some more opinios!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to this question need not be subjective. For his use case of game development ( involving lots of changing binary files ) and involvement of non-programmers, I would suggest SVN as SVN still has better handling of binary files ( through storage of diffs ) than Git and also, for a new comer, SVN is much more friendly than Git. In fact, I think Mercurial will be a good fit as well, but I feel TortoiseHg is not up to the mark with TortoiseSVN or TortoiseGit.

Comment: tanks for the answer after those 3 comment i was thinking how bad was this question!?

Comment: @KingCrunch - think I did make it subjective

Comment: @zerkms - Where did I say that? Is my english so bad? I am saying the other way way around - `TortosieHg is not up to the mark with TortoiseSVN or TortosieGit.`

Comment: *my* english *is* so bad ))) I thought that means that thg is worse.